# How do I get coordinates from a GPS service into a text file?

Tags: java, android, gps

I am new to Android programming. The source code that I have pasted is not my own, it is from a Github project. I want to save the coordinates of a GPS service into a textfile. Does anyone know how to do this?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button btn_start, btn_stop;
public Button save;

private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;
int delay = 1000; // delay for 1 sec.
int period = 10000; // repeat every 10 sec.
Timer timer = new Timer();
public EditText editText;
public TextView textView;

public String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/aaTutorial";

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(broadcastReceiver == null){
        broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                textView.append("\n" +intent.getExtras().get("coordinates"));

            }
        };
    }
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver,new IntentFilter("location_update"));
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if(broadcastReceiver != null){
        unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn_start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn_stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
    File dir = new File(path);
    dir.mkdirs();

    if(!runtime_permissions())
        enable_buttons();

}

private void enable_buttons() {

    btn_start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i =new Intent(getApplicationContext(),GPS_Service.class);
            startService(i);
        }
    });

    btn_stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),GPS_Service.class);
            stopService(i);

        }
    });

}

private boolean runtime_permissions() {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},100);

        return true;
    }
    return false;
}


@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if(requestCode == 100){
        if( grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            enable_buttons();
        }else {
            runtime_permissions();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make use of a `BufferedWriter`, and call `BufferedWriter.write()` method inside your `BroadcastReceiver.onReceive()`.

Assuming your current code works, here you can check the changes needed:

```
BufferedWriter writer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("mnt/sdcard/gps.txt"));
    //...

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(broadcastReceiver == null){
        broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                textView.append("\n" +intent.getExtras().get("coordinates"));

                writer.write(intent.getExtras().get("coordinates"));
                writer.newLine();

            }
        };
    }
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver,new IntentFilter("location_update"));
}

protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    writer.close();
    if(broadcastReceiver != null){
        unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
    }
}
```

Comment: I made the changes you suggested, but I get an error: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.io.BufferedWriter.write(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference. This error occurs in the try catch clause at try {
                            writer.write((String) intent.getExtras().get("coordinates"));
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();   This is for the method public void onReceive.